# No isometry of a manifold has the shadowing property

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

I am reading Brin and Stuck's book: Introduction to Dynamical Systems, chapter 5, about $\epsilon$-orbit.

Let $M$ is a $C^1$-Riemannian manifold, $U\subset M$ is an open subset, $f:U\rightarrow f(U)\subset M$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism. An $\textit{$\epsilon$-orbit}$ or pseudo-orbit of $f:U\rightarrow M$ is a finite or infinite sequence $(x_n)\subset U$ such that $d(f(x_n),x_{n+1})\leq\epsilon$ for all $n$.

An $\delta$-orbit is called $\epsilon$-approximated by a real orbit if there is $x\in U$ s.t $d(f^n(x),x_n)<\epsilon$, $f$ has the $\textit{shadowing property}$ if for every $\epsilon >0$, there is $\delta >0$ such that every $\delta$-orbit is $\epsilon$-approximated by a real orbit.

I am trying to prove that no isometry of a manifold has the shadowing property.

Example, let $R_\alpha : \mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1, x\mapsto x+\alpha \mod 1$. Suppose by contradiction that exists $(\epsilon,\delta)$ s.t every $\delta$-orbit is $\epsilon$-approximated by a real orbit. Choose $\delta'$ small enough s.t $\delta'\leq \min(\epsilon,\delta)$ and $\epsilon-\delta'$ is irrational. Then $n(\epsilon-\delta')$ for $n\geq 0$ is an $\delta$-orbit. And it is easy to show that this $\delta$-orbit can not be $\epsilon$-approximated by any real orbit.

I tried to apply this strategy for the general case but failed, it is hard to control $d(x,f^k(x))$.